# ExtGWT working with GWT UIBinder

Tags: uibinder, gxt

Is there any way to make ExtGWT work inside UIBinder ui.xml files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any widget could be added in the ui.xml file by first adding the library to the namespace xmlns:ext='urn:import:the.package.of.the.widgets.to.be.used and refer them like any other widget. Make sure to add the jar to the classpath. The following is the usage.

```
<ext:ext-widget name=.../>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to echo the answer already provided by Vinod R.
As an example, here is how you can add a GXT text field into GWT HTMLPanel. Notice the "ext" namespace.

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
             xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
             xmlns:ext="urn:import:com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form">


    <g:HTMLPanel >
            <ext:TextField/>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```